# JBOSS eap 7.0 unable to locate javax.faces.model.SelectItem class in JPA query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l65Xm.jpg)I have a EAR project (JSF/RICH FACES ,JPA 2.0) working in JBOSS AS 6.1 which i have to migrate to JBOSS EAP 7.0.  While deploying, i get following error in during creation of persistence unit.

```
**"[PersistenceUnit: changecdb] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: changecdb] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: getSubReports, getAllReports"}}}} "**
```

The logs show the following error:

```
**"ERROR [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) HHH000177: Error in named query: getSubReports: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate class [javax.faces.model.SelectItem] [select new javax.faces.model.SelectItem(r.id,r.name) from com.centurylink.changecejb.entity.Report r where r.id<>? order by r.name asc]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
"**
```

Below is the source file which contains the named queries:

```
package com.centurylink.changecejb.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;

@SequenceGenerator(name="reportSequence",sequenceName="rep_seq")
@Entity
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name="getAllCustomReports",query="select new com.centurylink.changecejb.bean.SelectBean(r.id,r.name) from Report r order by r.name asc")
,@NamedQuery(name="getCustomReportForAId",query="from Report r where r.id=? ")
,@NamedQuery(name="getSubReports",query="select new javax.faces.model.SelectItem(r.id,r.name) from Report r where r.id<>? order by r.name asc"),
@NamedQuery(name="getAllReports",query="select new javax.faces.model.SelectItem(r.id,r.name) from Report r order by r.name asc"),
@NamedQuery(name="updateCustomReport",query="update Report r  set r.name=:name where r.id=:id")

,@NamedQuery(name="deleteCustomReport",query="delete Report report where report.id=:id")})
@Table(name="report_table")
public class Report {
    private String filename;
    private String name;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="reportSequence",strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;
public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }
    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

I had not included the JSF api and impl , i did try to include those in my lib folder but still getting the same error.
Please help

UPDATE:

Below is my list of Library:

```
common-annotations.jar
commons-beanutils.jar
commons-collections.jar
commons-digester.jar
commons-logging.jar
cssparser-0.9.5.jar
guava-10.0.1.jar
guava-gwt-10.0.1.jar
jsonplugin-0.32.jar
jstl.jar
poi-3.6-20091214.jar
richfaces-components-api-4.2.0.Final.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.2.0.Final.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.2.0.Final.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.2.0.Final.jar
sac-1.3.jar
standard.jar
```

Below is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="changecdb" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/changec</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.centurylink.changecejb.entity.Report</class>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I am wondering if it is due to EAP 7.0 having Hibernate 5.0 where as AS6.1 has Hibernate 3.6 , and /or JSF 2.2 vs JSF 1.2

UPDATE:
On to taking que from answer by  Gabriel, I searched the EAP 7 libraries and found half of the libraries were already provided.  I deleted the libraries from my LIB which were already provided by EAP 7, still i am getting the same error. 
For some reason the HIBERNATE 5.0 is not  bale to load the class
**javax.faces.model.SelectItem**

I verifies that the class was present in one of the EAP 7.0 library under jaxax/faces module   **jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.12.redhat-1.jar**

Below is my current lib folder contents:

```
commons-digester.jar
commons-logging.jar
cssparser-0.9.5.jar
jsonplugin-0.32.jar
poi-3.6-20091214.jar
richfaces-components-api-4.2.0.Final.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.2.0.Final.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.2.0.Final.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.2.0.Final.jar
sac-1.3.jar
```

As a workaround I am thinking of providing my own JSF (1.2) as well as Hibernate (3.6) libraries and disable the EAP ones in standalone.xml.

Any other thoughts /suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a classpath related problem, maybe two versions of the same class are loaded. 
Check that you are not including a jar in your war that is provided by the server.
Can you add your libraries setup?

I see that you have jstl.jar and standard.jar that are provided by the platform. Not sure if that jars contain the problematic class, but anyhow you need to remove them.

**UPDATE**

As far as i know, JBoss EAP should be JEE6 compliant, thus it should be using JSF 2.0, and migrating to JBoss EAP (JEE7 compliant JSF 2.2) should be painless.

But you pointed out that you are using JSF 1.2, I'm guessing that you are using compatibility mode in JBoss EAP 6 as described in this [blog](http://tapas-tanmoy-bose.blogspot.mx/2014/01/how-to-run-jsf-12-application-in-jboss.html).

It seems that Wildfly/JBoss EAP 7 no longer support JSF 1.2, check [this page](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/StepsToAddAnyNewJSFImplementationOrVersionToWildFly) for instructions on how to add a custom JSF version.

Comment: Removed some jars which were provided by EAP including the one mentioned by you. still getting same error. Check updated post.

Comment: I think you misread AS 6.1 as EAP 6.0.     I am trying to migrate from(community version)   AS 6.1 to EAP 7.0 hence it was using JSF 1.2.    I simply removed all the jars related to JSF , but some how the class is not loaded by the namedquery.  I think i should test a JSF hello world first to make sure it is reading JSF library provided by EAP 7.0

Comment: You're right, I misread. You'll need to provide your custom JSF version.

Comment: I am trying to understand here, why the eap hibernate class loader not able to locate the jsf class in the eap  modules when I am not providing my custom  jars for either hibernate or jsf.  The named queries are static and hence are verified and loaded during deployment. What more do I have to do to load eap provided modules . My app is not using maven.